# Bash pipeline, duplicate stream and run different command in each line

Tags: bash, command-line

How could I run a different command on a second line of the output?

For example, I have `echo foo | sed p` which outputs

```
foo
foo
```

and I want to run `sed 's/foo/bar/'` on one of them to get

```
bar
foo
```

Comment: if its duplicated and command ran on it, it should be `foo` and next line should be `bar`? Either way, your input is not clear. Could you add a more demonstrative input/output

Answer (score 2):

In

```
$ echo foo | sed p
foo
foo
```

The first `foo` is printed by the `p` command, and the second, without `-n` because `sed` prints the pattern space as it is at the end of the cycle (just before reading in the next line).

To get `foo`, then `bar`, that would just be:

```
$ echo foo | sed 'p;s/foo/bar/'
foo
bar
```

Or:

```
$ echo foo | sed -n 'p;s/foo/bar/p'
foo
bar
```

For the `bar` to be printed (by the `s` command with the `p` flag when the substitution is successful) only if there was a substitution.

To get `bar`, then `foo`, you'd need to `h`old the original line and restore it after having printed the result of the substitution:

```
$ echo foo | sed 'h;s/foo/bar/p;g'
bar
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

to run a command which doesn't affect first line of data, you just need to run it in subshell, and prefix with a command which will read and output the first line, like this:

```
read -r line; echo "$line"   # pass first line unmodified
sed 's/foo/bar/'             # operate on rest of lines
```

so your whole example would look like this:

```
$ echo foo | sed p | ( read -r line; echo "$line"; sed 's/foo/bar/')
foo
bar
```

Comment: See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) (you missed the `IFS=`) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) (echo can't be used for arbitrary data).

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to pipe it into a command which can do different things depending on the input line number.

e.g., with `sed`:

```
$ printf 'foo\nfoo\n' | sed '2,$s/foo/bar/'
foo
bar
```

This uses sed's addressing syntax, to limit the `s/foo/bar/` operation to lines numbered from 2 to the end of the file (`2,$`).

From `man sed` (GNU version, reformatted slightly to make it more readable):

> Sed commands can be given with no addresses, in which case the
> command will be executed for all input lines; with one address,
> in which case the command will only be executed for input lines
> which match that address; or with two addresses, in which case
> the command will be executed for all input lines which match the
> inclusive range of lines starting from the first address and
> continuing to the second address.
>
> Three things to note about address ranges:
>
> - the syntax is addr1,addr2 (i.e., the addresses are separated
>   by a comma);
> - the line which addr1 matched will always be accepted, even if
>   addr2 selects an earlier line;
> - and if addr2 is a regexp, it will not be tested against the
>   line that addr1 matched.

or `awk`:

```
$ printf 'foo\nfoo\n' | awk 'NR > 1 {gsub(/foo/,"bar")};1'
foo
bar
```

or perl:

```
$ printf 'foo\nfoo\n' | perl -p -e 's/foo/bar/ if $. > 1'
foo
bar
```

The awk and perl versions test whether the line number (`NR` for awk, `$.` for perl) is greater than 1.